# Github API doesn't retrieve all the users when requested

Tags: axios, github-api

I have a project where I need to retrieve all the issues from a repo. I've been practicing with the atom repository and I am using the GitHub API.

I use axios get function and the request I'm making is the following.

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/issues',
  {
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw+json' },
    params: {'state': 'all'}
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But there are 772 issues and it is only retrieving 30 issues.

How can I retrive them all? am I missing something in the header or the params.

Ive also tried without params and the header. And also adding **filter: all** to the params and I still get 30 issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Muliple pages. Append to your URL, `?page=2` to get entries 31-60.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues).

Comment: And if I want pages form 2 to 30 in a single request? @MattClark

Comment: Probably unsupported by the API.

Comment: Will it be a good practice to make a request for each page? @MattClark